# Selecting relations from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm really stuck with a complex query in Postgresql. The use case is that the system has users, groups, and policies. A user can belong to multiple groups and a policy can belong to either a group or a user. This is modelled as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    username CHARACTER VARYING(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    hashed_password CHARACTER VARYING(64) NOT NULL,
  ldap BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "group" (
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  name CHARACTER VARYING(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "user_group" (
  user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  group_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user"(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES "group"(id)
);

CREATE TABLE "policy" (
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  user_id BIGINT,
  group_id BIGINT,
  effect VARCHAR(5),
  action TEXT,
  resource TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user"(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES "group"(id)
);
```

Now I need to check the user's policies based his user id combined with the policies based on the user's group and I want to join them with the user information.

I came up with this but this isn't showing while the user with `ID=1` should have policies because he is in the group with `ID=1`.

The data which is now in the policies is this this:

```
id=1
user_id=<null>
group_id=1
...
```

The query used is this:

```
SELECT
  p.effect,
  p.action,
  p.resource,
  u.*
FROM policy AS p
LEFT JOIN "user" AS u ON p.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN "group" AS g ON p.group_id = g.id
LEFT JOIN user_group AS ug ON u.id = ug.user_id
WHERE p.user_id = ug.user_id OR p.group_id = ug.group_id AND ug.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: show the query please

Comment: @VaoTsun added the query

Comment: Both `USER` and `GROUP` are reserved words. I prefer pluralis table names and singularis column names.

Comment: That final LEFT JOIN executes as a regular INNER JOIN thanks to the WHERE clause ug conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want policy records. So select from policy and use `EXISTS` or `IN` in your `WHERE` clause. You want all policies for user 1. This is where the policy's user ID is 1 or the policy's group ID is connected to this user.

There are only two tables needed: the policy table and the bridge table that links users to groups.

```
select *
from policy
where user_id = 1 
   or group_id in (select group_id from user_group where user_id = 1);
```

**UPDATE: You have altered your request. You want to show user information, too, now. That's an additional join.**

```
select *
from policy p
cross join (select * from "user" where id = 1) u
where p.user_id = 1 
   or p.group_id in (select group_id from user_group where user_id = 1);
```

And if you like it better, you can replace the two `= 1` in the main query's `WHERE` clause with `= u.id`. I do :-)

Comment: Sorry, that second query was nonsense. I'll update.... Should work now. You simply need a cross join with the user 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `join` conditions are wrong.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT p.effect, p.action, p.resource
FROM "user" u JOIN
     policy  p
     ON p.user_id = u.id JOIN
     user_group ug
     ON u.id = ug.user_id JOIN
     "group" g
     ON ug.group_id = g.id AND p.group_id = ug.group_id
WHERE ug.user_id = 1;
```

It is a little confusing on how the group in `policy` should related to the group in `user_groups`.

Comment: A user inherits policies from the group he is in. This query isn't giving any results